# Can't get Yahoo Weather XML file - Server Hangups

Tags: yahoo-weather-api

I am using yahoo weather for a while now.
Last week I started getting server hangups - I'm using the same link, sometimes It works, sometimes it doesn't.
Does anyone know whether there is an issue with Yahoo servers?

Here is the link I'm using:
[Yahoo! Weather for Auckland](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D2348079%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

This is the XML it returns:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2017-05-16T07:46:48Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<diagnostics>
<publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
<url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="1337" execution-time="1336" http-status-code="502" http-status-message="Server Hangup">
<![CDATA[
http://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com:4080/v3/public/weather/rss?u=c&w=2348079
]]>
</url>
<user-time>1339</user-time>
<service-time>1336</service-time>
<build-version>2.0.118</build-version>
</diagnostics>
<results/>
</query>
<!--  total: 1339  -->
<!--
 prod_bf1_1;paas.yql;queryyahooapiscomproductionbf1;a9411888-2c54-11e7-b972-d4ae52974741
```

Comment: Could you please define "server hangups"  what exactly are you seeing?

Comment: that is the error return in the XML: http-status-code="502" http-status-message="Server Hangup"

Comment: Well there you go!

Comment: I didn't ask what the error is - I told that this is the problem. I asked if someone know the reason fo it since I'm using the same link for the last year.